# @Override annotation error in ClientProxy

Tags: java, minecraft

So, I have been working on a top-secret mod for minecraft that does things. I have already tried removing the @Override annotation. I am following the tutorial at ShadowFacts.net for 1.11, but am using Eclipse Java Mars rather than Intellij IDEA. This is my ClientProxy code:

```
package darkdoesstuff.elementalscience.proxy;

import darkdoesstuff.elementalscience.Reference;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader;

public class ClientProxy {
    @Override   /**This is where the error is*/
    public void registerItemRenderer(Item item, int meta, String id) {
        ModelLoader.setCustomModelResourceLocation(item, meta, new ModelResourceLocation(Reference.MODID + ":" + id, "inventory"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it say `public class ClientProxy extends SOMETHING`?

Comment: Well if you want to @override something you better extend some class (you miss some extends... after "class ClientProxy")

Comment: ["Create two new classes, CommonProxy and ClientProxy (I usually use a proxy package to keep this contained from the rest of the code) **and have ClientProxy extend CommonProxy**"](http://shadowfacts.net/tutorials/forge-modding-1102/proxy-system/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Override` annotation means that method realization below overrides (gives custom realization of) an existing one in superclass. Your problem is that you do not extend or implement any class.

So just remove the annotation.

Small example:

```
class A{
@Override //gives you an error
public void doSomething(){}
}

class B extends A {

@Override //cool here!
public void doSomething(){}

@Override  //error as well
public void doAnotherThing(){}
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the tutorial doesnt mention implementing a supertype method... Any ideas on what class it might be? maybe the CommonProxy... EDIT: Yup. Making the ClientProxy extend the CommonProxy worked.